# How to debug SQLite source code with Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, debugging, sqlite

I would like to debug an instance of a SQLite database created from modified SQLite code. As a user selects some data from the database I'd like to step through the SQLite source code and see what the logic of SQLite is. The purpose for this is I would like to see if I can add a SELECT trigger to the SQLite source code and create a SQLite database with my new type of trigger in it. Currently SQLite only supports triggers on UPDATE, INSERT & DELETE.

So far I've downloaded the "amalgamation" SQLite source code from http://www.sqlite.org/index.html and managed to build it in Visual Studio 2010. I have no idea how to debug against it however. I tried creating a test C# web application that used the SQLite project as a project reference - but it won't let me add it as a reference (Throws an error saying "A reference to 'mySQLiteproj' could not be added" which is SOOO useful). My current structure is simply an empty C project with the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h files in it.

The SQLite code is written in C, which I am unfamiliar with, so maybe I'm going completely down the wrong path? I am coming from a C# background so please don't suggest I scrap using Visual Studio and instead use Notepad or some other "hardcore" IDE :)

In short: **How do I debug SQLite Source Code?**

**Edit:** I've added the shell.c file to the project as suggested by Sergey and can now "sort of" debug. It will hit breakpoints in shell.c, but not sqlite3.c. I can step into sqlite3.c as a function call from shell.c, but the lines don't seem to match up with what code is running. Half the lines are greyed out (by resharper perhaps?) and there is no auto-watch of variables or highlighting of which line the code is currently breaking on.

Comment: I've created cmake-based build for SQLite amalgamation here https://github.com/snikulov/sqlite.cmake.build so you can generate Visual Studio solution, build it as Debug target and then debug. Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To debug library code written on a language you "unfamiliar with", it is better to start from the beginning.

Here the algorithm:

1. Learn language (C)
2. Learn your tools (debugger in Visual Studio)
3. Learn the target (SQLite - is library which provides API for others, so you need set breakpoints on SQLite API for example sqlite3_open() and "Run" shell.c source file in Visual Studio)

I've created [cmake-based build for SQLite amalgamation](http://github.com/snikulov/sqlite.cmake.build) so you can generate Visual Studio solution, build it as Debug target and then debug. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: 1) I am unfamiliar with C, but I have coded with it about 15 years ago. 2) I am intimately familiar with Visual Studio debugger as I have used it every day for the past 8 years. 3) I am starting to learn SQLite which is why I have posted this question. I was asking for a specific help in setting up a project - not a generalisation. Perhaps I did not phrase the question clearly enough for you to answer usefully?

Comment: @JumpingJezza Sorry, man if I hurt you. But my intro provides clean way to start debugging. Then you just need to omit two first steps. Ah, and yes - thanks for down-vote.

Comment: How does your answer help me work out how to run a instance of a sqlite database and debug against it? To quote the downvote "This answer is not useful"

Comment: Why not? In amalgamation we have not only sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h but also shell.c which uses SQLite API. Just add it to your solution rebuild in debug mode and run (don't forget to add breakpoint on API you wish to debug before). That is all. It is exact answer to your question "How do I debug SQLite Source Code?" provided under 3.